# Junit fails due to Aspect

Tags: maven, aspectj, compile-time, load-time-weaving, compile-time-weaving

I have a custom security framwork based on annotations.I use the aspectj maven plugin to weave the aspect when it comes across the security annotation for the method.

I use jenkins to build the project and the aspectj maven plugin goals are set for compile as given below.

```
    <plugin>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
            <artifactId>aspectj-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>1.4</version>
            <dependencies>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
                    <artifactId>aspectjrt</artifactId>
                    <version>1.6.5</version>
                </dependency>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
                    <artifactId>aspectjtools</artifactId>
                    <version>1.6.5</version>
                </dependency>
            </dependencies>
            <configuration>
                <showWeaveInfo>true</showWeaveInfo>
                <complianceLevel>1.6</complianceLevel>
                <!-- <weaveDirectories> <weaveDirectory>${project.build.directory}/classes</weaveDirectory> 
                    </weaveDirectories> -->
            </configuration>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <!-- Compile and weave aspects after all classes compiled by javac -->
                    <phase>process-classes</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>compile</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
```

The problem comes when the junit runs.Since it had already weaved the security related annotations in the methods,the unit test fails.

Is there a way where I can have the junits work and then do the aspectj weaving?
Since I use a .aj file separately I am not sure how load time weaving can be set.

Any help on this is appreciated.

Regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I reorganised my maven goals into

clean compile test aspectj:compile

so after testing the aspectj weaving is done which is all I wanted.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add test-compile to your goals, I think.

```
<goals>
    <goal>compile</goal>
    <goal>test-compile</goal>
</goals>
```